# cakephp 3.4.5 Authntication issue

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-3.4

I have just configured the cakephp 3.4 (by oven) . I am trying to ingrate authentication to my application, so I have configured users table, model, controller and app controller setup. But I am getting "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'cakephp.users' doesn't exist" after login form submit Even I have users table exists in database. Can anyone please suggest me what is going wrong?

Comment: Have you configured the correct database for the CakePHP application?

Comment: yes, i have already checked it.